# steam severely glitches unless opened in terminal

Tags: steam

when steam is opened all the windows glitch severely. some are black, some datamosh-like static. can't make out a thing. when I open in terminal this doesn't happen. tried reinstalling & purging steam. updated drivers. anyone have any idea what's wrong? thanks

Comment: What exact command is run when you open steam from the gui? Is it different from what you type in the terminal?

Comment: What GPU do you have? Are you running inside a Wayland session? Perhaps logout and back in, with an Xorg session, if so.

Comment: Are you running Steam beta?

Comment: hi sorry I sorted this out thanks. had to switch to sea islands card in command line*